# How to find five consequential equal values in pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Hello a have table like this

```
Application     DATE        STATUS
--------------------------------------
Application 1   10-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   11-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   12-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   13-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   14-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   15-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   16-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   17-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   18-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   19-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   20-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   21-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 1   22-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   23-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 1   25-MAR-17   SUCCEEDED
Application 3   20-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   21-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   22-MAR-17   FAILED
Application 3   23-MAR-17   FAILED
```

and I have to find five consequential failed status starting with  latest date backward. I'll be happy with some help for my case.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not for questions like "How to do this", so you should do some search first, try something and then, if you are stuck on some code, ask a question

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: I have to find application with five consequential failes statuses.

Comment: Of course i tired a few thinks like self join and lag function, but thats not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, your goal is to find any `Application` whose five most recent runs are all `FAILED` status.

`PL/SQL` is not required to achieve this goal; it can be achieved with normal `SQL`.
If compiling into a procedure is required, the SQL can be incorporated into the procedure block as needed.

Below is an example, though it should be noted there are many ways to get this kind of data.

First, create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION_RUN (APPLICATION_NAME VARCHAR2(64), EVENT_DATE DATE, EVENT_STATUS VARCHAR2(64));
```

Then load the data.

Some additional data is included in this example, since your post doesn't have any examples of 5 most recent executions all being failures.
This data includes 5+ recent failures for `Application 3`, and a stretch of 5+ old failures for `Application 1`.  There is also an `Application 4` that has a only single failure (hasn't been run 5x yet).

```
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('10-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('11-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('12-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('13-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('14-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('15-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('16-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('17-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('18-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('19-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('20-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('21-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('22-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('23-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 1',TO_DATE('25-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('24-MAR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('20-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('21-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('22-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('23-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('24-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('25-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 4',TO_DATE('25-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'FAILED');
```

Then query.
This example has three steps:
First, rank the application-runs by their date, most recent first.
Then, throw out all but the most recent five and throw anything with less than 5 runs total.
Finally check that all five of these are `FAILED` or not.  This example query is laid out with named subfactor queries, to highlight these goals.

```
WITH FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN AS (
   SELECT
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     EVENT_DATE,
     EVENT_STATUS
   FROM
     (SELECT
        APPLICATION_RUN.APPLICATION_NAME,
        APPLICATION_RUN.EVENT_DATE,
        APPLICATION_RUN.EVENT_STATUS,
        DENSE_RANK()
        OVER (
          PARTITION BY APPLICATION_RUN.APPLICATION_NAME
          ORDER BY EVENT_DATE DESC ) AS EVENT_RANK
      FROM APPLICATION_RUN) RANKED_APPLICATION_RUN
   WHERE RANKED_APPLICATION_RUN.EVENT_RANK < 6),
    RUN_STATUS_VARIATION AS (
     SELECT
       FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN.APPLICATION_NAME,
       COUNT(DISTINCT FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN.EVENT_STATUS) AS STATUS_VARIATIONS,
       MAX(FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN.EVENT_STATUS)
       KEEP
       (DENSE_RANK FIRST
         ORDER BY FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN.EVENT_DATE DESC)  AS MOST_RECENT_STATUS
     FROM FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN
     GROUP BY FIVE_MOST_RECENT_RUN.APPLICATION_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 4)
SELECT RUN_STATUS_VARIATION.APPLICATION_NAME
FROM RUN_STATUS_VARIATION
WHERE RUN_STATUS_VARIATION.STATUS_VARIATIONS = 1
      AND RUN_STATUS_VARIATION.MOST_RECENT_STATUS = 'FAILED';
```

Then test it:

```
APPLICATION_NAME  
Application 3
```

If you add a new, `SUCCEEDED` run for `Application 3` more recent than the others, `Application 3` is no longer returned by the query.

```
INSERT INTO APPLICATION_RUN VALUES ('Application 3',TO_DATE('26-APR-17','DD-MON-YY'),'SUCCEEDED');
```

And run again:

```
no rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks @ПоляМиленкова If you have any questions about this approach just let me know. There are other approaches as well with different trade-offs. If this(or another answer) has answered your question, please consider accepting an answer.  Thanks